# HTML Form Pattern / Validation

Tags: html, regex, validation

I am trying to come up with a valid pattern for an HTML form. I would like to allow all upper & lower case letters, spaces, numbers, and the symbols / \ @ # $ % & .

I've tried a couple different formats but I haven't had any luck.

So far I have:

```
<input type="text" name="Address" size="25"  pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{2,35}]" title="Title" required/>
```

Comment: you mean you want all the things?

Comment: no. he doesn't want ! , ? | and other punctuation characters :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example I built with w3schools test page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit="getElementById('s').innerHTML=getElementById('i').value;return false;">
  Country code: <input id="i" type="text" name="country_code" pattern="([a-zA-Z0-9]| |/|\\|@|#|\$|%|&)+" title="Three letter country code">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<p>Submitted value: <span id="s">
```

Note: The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

You can use it to make your own tests at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern

Comment: Your regular expression pattern isn't quite correct. The correct one is `([a-zA-Z0-9]| |/|\\|@|#|\$|%|&)+`, or `[a-zA-Z0-9 /\\@#$%&]+`.